# Powershell to add users to custom security groups - getting 0x80070005 error

Tags: powershell, security

The following powershell reads an xml file and adds users to custom SharePoint security groups.

```
If ([bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")) 
{
  write-host "You are an administrator" 
}

RegisterSharePointSnapin

$xmlUsersFileFullPath = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) "xml-config/Users-In-Security-Groups.xml"
$xmlUsers = [xml](get-content $xmlUsersFileFullPath)
[System.Xml.XmlElement] $groupRoot = $xmlUsers.get_DocumentElement()
$tab = "`t" 

write-host "Adding users to the following groups..." -ForegroundColor Gray 

# Get the site and group names
$web = Get-SPWeb $inputSite
#$web.Name, $web.Title , $web.Url

foreach ($g in $groupRoot.group)
{
    [string]$groupLabel = $g.Name        

    if ($g.HasChildNodes)
    {

        $groupName = $web.SiteGroups[$groupLabel]

        foreach ($u in $g.user)
        {         
            #$gotUser = !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($u))

            $user = $web.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser($u)

            $user
            $groupName

            $groupName.AddUser($user)
            if ($error.count -eq 0)
            {
                Write-Host "$tab $u Added Successfully to $groupLabel" -ForegroundColor DarkGray;
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "$tab    $u Failed, not added to $groupLabel" -ForegroundColor Red;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It works on 'my' machine but on the test farm I get the following error

```
Exception calling "AddUser" with "1" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
At D:\Deployment\SharePoint\Deploy-Scripts\Add-Users-To-Security-
Groups.ps1:64 char:31
+             $groupName.AddUser <<<< ($user)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

            domain\username01 Failed, not added to my-security-groupname
```

The output from the script confirms its running as an administrator, the $user and $groupName variables hold correct information. The logged in user is a user that has access to Central Admin and successfully runs other deployment scripts that add/remove sharepoint solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Searching on the 0x80070005 error indicated it is due to permissions.

Checked the "site collection administrators" for the site in question and the logged in user although having access to Central Admin, wasn't there.

Made the logged in user a site collection admin and script was successful.